# Why does the controller not get injected when testing .zul page with Zats?

Tags: java, spring, junit, zk

I am trying to implement a first Zats test and got stuck because of missing Spring dependency injection.

The test with the code snippets from below goes green, but *doAfterCompose* is never called. It seems that the controller injection into the zul page does not work. Changing the *apply="${teamsPopupCtrl}"* to a full qualified name, the controller gets used, but *teamService* is null and I got a NullPointerException when *teamService.findAll()* is called from *doAfterCompose*. So again it seems that nothing gets injected.

The ApplicationContext itself is loading without any error and using *@Autowired private TeamService teamService;* for verification in my test class works as expected. When firstTest is executed, teamService is not null.

I also tried to use

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
```

in zul page but that only leads to

```
IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:56851/teamsPopup.zul
```

which I could not specify any further.

**Zul page:**

```
<?page id="teamsPopup" title="layout" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <window apply="${teamsPopupCtrl}" width="400px" title="Fachteams" border="normal" closable="true">
        <listbox id="teamsList" multiple="true" checkmark="true" width="380px" mold="paging" pageSize="10">
            <listhead><listheader label="Fachteams" /></listhead>           
        </listbox>
        <hbox height="10px" />
        <toolbar mold="panel" align="center">
            <button id="btnOk" forward="onOK" label="OK" mold="trendy" height="25px" width="120px" image="./images/ok.png" />
            <button forward="onClose" label="Abbruch" mold="trendy" height="25px" width="120px" image="./images/cancel.png" />
        </toolbar>
    </window>
</zk>
```

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext/test-applicationContext.xml"})
public class TeamsPopupTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        Zats.init("./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/schemaOverview");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
        Zats.end();
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        Zats.cleanup();
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() throws Exception {
        final DesktopAgent desktop = Zats.newClient().connect("/teamsPopup.zul");
    }
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class TeamsPopupCtrl extends AbstractPopupCtrl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1945118180857183121L;

    // ZK Autowire
    Listbox teamsList;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("teamsPopupModel")
    private PopupModel popupModel;

    @Autowired
    private TeamService teamService;

    // ZK Autowire
    private Listbox teamsBox;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(final Window comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        this.teamsList.setItemRenderer(new TeamListBoxRenderer());
        this.teamsList.setModel(getFilteredTeamList());
    }

    public SchemaModel getSchemaModel() {
        return (SchemaModel) getPerspectiveController().getCurrentPerspective().getModel();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public void onOK(final Event event) {
        final ListModelList<?> model = (ListModelList<?>) this.teamsList.getModel();
        final List<Team> selectedTeams = new ArrayList(model.getSelection());
        this.teamService.addTeamsToNodeInSchema(getSchemaModel().getCurrentNode(), selectedTeams);
        this.teamsBox.setModel(new ListModelList<NodeTeamAssociation>(getSchemaModel().getCurrentNode().getNodeTeamList()));
        doClosePopup();
        if (!model.getSelection().isEmpty()) {
            modify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doOpenPopup(final org.zkoss.zul.Window window) {
        super.doOpenPopup(window);
        Executions.createComponents("/WEB-INF/pages/schemaOverview/teamsPopup.zul", getModel().getPopupWindow(), null);
    }

    private ListModelList<Team> getFilteredTeamList() {
        final Collection<Team> allTeams = new ArrayList<Team>(this.teamService.findAll());
        for (final NodeTeamAssociation selectedTeam : getSchemaModel().getCurrentNode().getNodeTeamList()) {
            allTeams.remove(selectedTeam.getTeam());
        }
        return new ListModelList<Team>(allTeams);
    }

    protected class TeamListBoxRenderer implements ListitemRenderer<Team>, Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8268285374821502239L;

        @Override
        public void render(final Listitem item, final Team teamdata, final int index) throws Exception {
            final Listcell lc = new org.zkoss.zul.Listcell();
            lc.setLabel(teamdata.getName());
            lc.setValue(teamdata);
            lc.setParent(item);
            TeamsPopupCtrl.this.teamsList.setMultiple(true);
            TeamsPopupCtrl.this.teamsList.setCheckmark(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected PopupModel getModel() {
        return this.popupModel;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get the test work with dependency injection or what I am missing in my test setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's probably somethings to do with your ZATS environment settings.

Knows that ZATS are actually using Jetty to run your application, because it require "real" components from the running application to run those tests. Therefore, ZATS must be set up exactly like how you run your application.

In your test setup code, I saw you only call

```
Zats.init("./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/schemaOverview");
```

If this is the only setup you do, then ZATS will use its own **web.xml** & **zk.xml** to run your application. I think that's why spring dose not work at all, because it never been loaded.

You can check this document to set ZATS load **web.xml** & **zk.xml** from the position you want.

[ZATS : Customize Test Environment](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZATS%20Essentials/Mimic%20Library/Advanced%20Usage/Customize%20Test%20Environment)

Comment: I tried to setup my own ZatsEnvironment but I am not sure how to do it correctly.web.xml and zk.xml are not in the same folder.

Comment: In that case, you may want to copy your web.xml, zk.xml to the other place, and let ZATS to load it from there. Such as `./src/test/zats-config`